# How do I register the AlarmManager to repeat selected days?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm creating an alarm application.

In my application, the user can select the days to fire the alarm, such as Sunday, Monday, so I used the Calendar class and AlarmManager to register multiple alarms.

If the selected day or days are less than the current day of the week, the alarm fires immediately.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, getDayint); //sunday = 1
calendar.set(calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, gethour);
calendar.set(calendar.MINUTE, getmin);
calendar.set(calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

long TIM = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, TIM, sender);

//repeat weekly
am.setRepeating(am.RTC,TIM, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*7, sender);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT you say that you like to have only one such alarm - so latest one wins - only one alarm weekly.  And if TIM lies in past, alarm is fired immediately ( and then repeating )  So far - everything works as designed.

You may check whether TIM ( by the way, it is variable, and concention is that they shall be not uppercased like constants )  is less than System.currentTimeMillis() and add one week to it in this case